# Make a group aggregation base on timestamp, and get the field values in front of it in Arrays MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Mongo DB Array Structure:

```json
[
   {
      "time":[
         "2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z",
         "2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z",
         "2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z",
         "2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z",
         "2017-09-17T11:16:54.500Z",
         "2017-09-17T11:16:54.500Z",
         "2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z"
      ],
      "foo":[
         2,
         5,
         9,
         6,
         3,
         7,
         8
      ]
   },
   {
      "time":[
         "2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z",
         "2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z",
         "2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z",
         "2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z",
         "2017-09-17T11:16:54.500Z",
         "2017-09-17T11:16:54.500Z",
         "2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z"
      ],
      "bar":[
         7,
         8,
         9,
         4,
         7,
         7,
         4
      ]
   }
]
```

Expected output One document base on time.:

```json
{
   "_id":{
      "time":"2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z"
   },
   "time":"2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z",
   "data":{
      "foo":2,
      "bar":7
   },

"_id":{
      "time":""2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z"
   },
   "time":""2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z",
   "data":{
      "foo":5,
      "bar":8
   },
"_id":{
      "time":"2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z"
   },
   "time":"2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z",
   "data":{
      "foo":9,
      "bar":9
   },
"_id":{
      "time":"2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z"
   },
   "time":"2016-11-14T10:16:32.700Z",
   "data":{
      "foo":6,
      "bar":4
   },
"_id":{
      "time":"2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z"
   },
   "time":"2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z",
   "data":{
      "foo":3,
      "bar":7
   },

}
```

I have multiple documents with the name `foo` and `bar`.
I want to do the group with respect to time, and Output will be a One-time stamp and that contains No value or Multiple values of the `bar` and `foo` and get multiple documents with respect to time.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Your timestamp has multiple values, how does foo got 2 and bar got 7?

Comment: Its first element of the arrays, At the end, we should get one document, that must contain the time, foo and bar values are optional.values are depend on time if bar and foo have value with respect to time. It's a part of the document, otherwise, it's just a time in the document.

Comment: Yes,  time "2018-12-18T20:16:28.800Z" your input or pick first time from array and return single document? foo and bar are dynamic keys.

Comment: I need to get it from the array, but each document gets one timestamp from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$project`, `$map` to iterate loop of range from `0` to size of `time` array using `$range`, return specific fields,

  - `time` get element using `$arrayElemAt`
  - `index` get index from range
  - `data` make object, `$reduce` to iterate loop of `$$ROOT` fields after converting to array using `$objectToArray`, check condition in if field name is from `foo/bar` then it will get element from number array and return after converting using `$arrayToObject`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `datas` array
- `$group` by time and index and make data as object
- `$sort` by index field ascending order

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      datas: {
        $map: {
          input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$time" }] },
          as: "a",
          in: {
            time: { $arrayElemAt: ["$time", "$$a"] },
            index: "$$a",
            data: {
              $reduce: {
                input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                initialValue: {},
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    { $in: ["$$this.k", ["foo", "bar"]] },
                    {
                      $arrayToObject: [[
                          {
                            k: "$$this.k",
                            v: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$this.v", "$$a"] }
                          }
                      ]]
                    },
                    {}
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$datas" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        index: "$datas.index",
        time: "$datas.time"
      },
      time: { $first: "$datas.time" },
      data: { $mergeObjects: "$datas.data" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "_id.index": 1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w8nFN9ZvmWV)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in that case, I get only one document, I need my all documents with respect to time. for example, here I have 7 values, so 7 documents with respect to time

Comment: I update the expected output, I get multiple values documents, w.r.t time.

Comment: [AskAnotherQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65778870/merge-multiple-documents-into-one-document-with-both-document-fields-in-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment116301306_65778870) 
Hi, @turivishal can you check another question 
Thanks in advance

Comment: [JustPostedNewQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349339/how-to-match-on-the-object-level-in-mongodb)@turivishal can you please answer, if you did not understand it, let me know