# How to match on the object level in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Input Documents**

```
  "data": {
    "abc": {
      "Id": "100"

    },
    "xyz": {
      "Id": "123"
    }
}
```

**Explanation**  :
I want to do the `$match` on `data.{i}  i is parameter`  if I give to `"abc" as a parameter`
I get the following output, I want to pass the multiple parameters to  `i` `"abc", "xyz"..` 
How I can do that in do that $match the object key using parameter.

**Expected Output** :

```
  "data": {
    "abc": {
      "Id": "100"
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you add an input example and expected output?

Comment: Input example is I put it as Input document, and expected output I put with respect to parameter, If you did not understand the problem can we discuss on chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check the key is exists or not using `$exists`
- project that key,

```
let i = "abc";
Schema.find(
  { ["data."+i]: { $exists: true } },
  { ["data."+i]: 1 }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r96Lg_48CGS)

---

Second option if you have list of keys in array,

- map through prepare a query for `$or` condition, and prepare project part

```
let i = ["abc", "xyz"];
let query = [], project = {};
i.map(k => {
  query.push({ ["data."+k]: { $exists: true } });
  project["data."+k] = 1;
});

Schema.find({ $or: query }, project);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_VijppZQ4KC)

---

Third option using project operators starting from MongoDb v4.4, with more dynamic approach,

- `$objectToArray` convert object to array
- `$filter` to filter above converted array and get matching elements
- `$arrayToObject` convert array back to object

```
let i = "abc";
Schema.find(
  { ["data."+i]: { $exists: true } },
  {
    data: {
      $arrayToObject: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$data" },
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.k", i] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mGS2r0NNc1N)

Comment: but, I have a list of keys, how I can check it, is "abc" in my case will be a parameter? because I need to give the list value that needs to match

Comment: list of keys available in array?

Comment: its not array, but I can convert the "data" to "objectToArray" then we have key, value,  did you get my point?

Comment: yes i got your point but its heavy transaction for only matching and selecting fields, we can do that. i will share you that way as well.

Comment: is it possible I can use the aggregation instead of Schema.find?

Comment: yes it is possible just move find query in $match stage and move project in $project stage.

Comment: but somehow I get an error message because of array [], an error message is: Failed to build valid JSON syntax. Unexpected character ('['

Comment: [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mGS2r0NNc1N) here you fix the parameter "data.abc" but in my case, I did not understand how i can set the parameter at key level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229194/discussion-between-bc110402922-and-turivishal).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let keys = ["abc"];

db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "filteredData": {
                $filter: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$data" },
                    as: "item",
                    cond: {
                        $in: ["$$item.k", keys]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            data: { $arrayToObject: "$filteredData" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output: When array `keys = ["abc"];`

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60395e36e0c7d52970d3fa21"),
    "data" : {
        "abc" : {
            "Id" : "100"
        }
    }
}
```

Output: When array `keys = ["abc", "xyz"];`

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60395e36e0c7d52970d3fa21"),
    "data" : {
        "abc" : {
            "Id" : "100"
        },
        "xyz" : {
            "Id" : "123"
        }
    }
}
```