# MongoDB - match all nested object property paths dynamically

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

[image]

The above is the structure of my data in the MongoDB Store. Let's say im querying as follows

`{'symbol_alerts.[CHANNEL_ID_STRING].usdt_alerts: {$exists: true}}`

I want to dynamically match all the `CHANNEL_ID_STRINGS` inside the `symbol_alerts`path, so i can query the existence of `usdt_subs` within all the channels. Any idea how i can match all `CHANNEL_ID_STRING`s regardlelss of its value?

Answer (score 2):

Solution #1:

```js
var CHANNEL_ID_STRING = "abc"

var condition = {}

condition[`symbol_alerts.${CHANNEL_ID_STRING}.usdt_alerts`] = { $exists: true };

db.dynamicKeys.find(condition);
```

Solution #2 based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349339/how-to-match-on-the-object-level-in-mongodb/66350728#66350728):

```js
let CHANNEL_ID_STRING = "abc";

db.dynamicKeys.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            dynamicKeys: { $objectToArray: "$symbol_alerts" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "dynamicKeys": {
                $elemMatch: {
                    k: CHANNEL_ID_STRING,
                    "v.usdt_alerts": { $exists: true }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "symbol_alerts": { $arrayToObject: "$dynamicKeys" }
        }
    }
]);
```

And this how my sample collection looks like:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:2/24/2021, 8:08:54 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603664fe24f3423874ac9534"),
    "symbol_alerts" : {
        "jkl" : {
            "other_key" : {
                "key1" : "value1"
            }
        },
        "mno" : {
            "usdt_alerts" : {
                "key1" : "value1"
            }
        }
    }
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/24/2021, 8:08:54 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603664fe24f3423874ac9533"),
    "symbol_alerts" : {
        "abc" : {
            "usdt_alerts" : {
                "key1" : "value1"
            }
        },
        "def" : {
            "other_key" : {
                "key1" : "value1"
            }
        },
        "ghi" : {
            "usdt_alerts" : {
                "key1" : "value1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is using dynamic programming. But is there any way to do it only use Mongo Queries? Like maybe a Regex filter?

Comment: So now it is "dynamic" at the MongoDB level. I don't know how you want the filter result to look like. If u update the question I will modify the query.